# how to remove null values after union join in maria db?

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

[image]

After the union the result is given above
I want to remove the empty field in test_values column
the query used for union is

> ```
> > SELECT tt.test_name,tt.test_category,report.test_values,tt.unit FROM
> > report LEFT JOIN tt ON report.test_id = tt.id UNION SELECT
> > tt.test_name,tt.test_category,report.test_values,tt.unit FROM report
> > RIGHT JOIN tt ON report.test_id = tt.id where test_values IS NOT NULL
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Its Silly,I have not defined NULL in query this is how i solved this
it don't return the NULL value instead it return the '' string

```
 SELECT tt.test_name,tt.test_category,report.test_values,tt.unit FROM report LEFT JOIN tt ON report.test_id = tt.id where test_values!='' union
                        SELECT tt.test_name,tt.test_category,report.test_values,tt.unit FROM report RIGHT JOIN tt ON report.test_id = tt.id where test_values!=''
```